# Managing and debugging SQL queries in MS Access

Tags: sql, debugging, ms-access

MS Access has limited capabilities to manage raw SQL queries: the editor is quite bad, no syntax highlighting, it reformats your raw SQL into a long string and you can't insert comments.

Debugging complex SQL queries is a pain as well: either you have to split it into many smaller queries that become difficult to manage when your schema changes or you end-up with a giant query that is a nightmare to debug and update.

How do you manage your complex SQL queries in MS Access and how do you debug them?

**Edit**
At the moment, I'm mostly just using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) for some syntax colouring and [SQL Pretty Printer](http://www.wangz.net/) for reformatting sensibly the raw SQL from Access.
Using an external repository is useful but keeping there's always the risk of getting the two versions out of sync and you still have to remove comments before trying the query in Access...

Comment: I wonder if you are asking about logical bugs as opposed to syntax errors.  That's relevant in determining my approach.

Answer (score 15):

For debugging, I edit them in a separate text editor that lets me format them sensibly.  When I find I need to make changes, I edit the version in the text editor, and paste it back to Access, never editing the version in Access.

Still a major PITA.

Answer (score 13):

I have a few tips that are specific to SQL in VBA.

Put your SQL code with a string variable.  I used to do this:

```
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ...")
```

That is hard to manage.  Do this instead:

```
strSQL = "SELECT ..."
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Often you can't fix a query unless you see just what's being run.  To do that, dump your SQL to the Immediate Window just before execution:

```
strSQL = "SELECT ..."
Debug.Print strSQL
Stop
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Paste the result into Access' standard query builder (you must use *SQL view*).  Now you can test the final version, including code-handled variables.

When you are preparing a long query as a string, break up your code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT wazzle FROM bamsploot" _
      & vbCrLf & "WHERE plumsnooker = 0"
```

I first learned to use `vbCrLf` when I wanted to prettify long messages to the user.  Later I found it makes SQL more readable while coding, and it improves the output from `Debug.Print`.  (Tiny other benefit:  no space needed at end of each line.  The new line syntax builds that in.)

(NOTE:  You might think this will let you add add comments to the right of the SQL lines.  Prepare for disappointment.)

As said elsewhere here, trips to a text editor are a time-saver.  Some text editors provide better syntax highlighting than the official VBA editor.  (Heck, StackOverflow does better.)  It's also efficient for deleting Access cruft like superfluous table references and piles of parentheses in the WHERE clause.

**Work flow for serious trouble shooting:**

```
VBA Debug.Print >       (capture query during code operation)
  query builder   >     (testing lab to find issues)
     Notepad++      >   (text editor for clean-up and review)
  query builder   >     (checking, troubleshooting) 
VBA
```

Of course, trouble shooting is usually a matter of reducing the complexity of a query until you're able to isolate the problem (or at least make it disappear!).  Then you can build it back up to the masterpiece you wanted.  Because it can take several cycles to solve a sticky problem, you are likely to use this work flow repeatedly.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote [Access SQL Editor](https://www.fieldeffect.info/purchase/)-- an Add-In for Microsoft Access-- because I write quite a lot of pass-through queries, and more complex SQL within Access.  This add-in has the advantage of being able to store formatted SQL (with comments!) within your Access application itself.  When queries are copied to a new Access application, formatting is retained.  When the built-in editor clobbers your formatting, the tool will show your original query and notify you of the difference.

It currently does not debug; if there was enough interest, I would pursue this-- but for the time being the feature set is intentionally kept small.

It is not free for the time being, but [purchasing](https://www.fieldeffect.info/purchase/) a license is very cheap. If you can't afford it, you can [contact me](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/access-sql-editor-documentation/).  There is a free 14-day trial [here](https://www.fieldeffect.info/trial/).

Once it's installed, you can access it through your Add-Ins menu (In Access 2010 it's Database Tools->Add Ins).

Comment: Your plug in quite what I had in mind when I asked the question. It doesn't help directly for debugging, but it helps making SQL queries maintainable. (Full disclosure: @transistor1 offered me a license after I tried the plugin).

Comment: Thank you very much - this is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Debugging is more of a challenge. If a single column is off, that's usually pretty easy to fix. But I'm assuming you have more complex debugging tasks that you need to perform.

When flummoxed, I typically start debugging with the `FROM` clause. I trace back to all the tables and sub-queries that comprise the larger query, and make sure that the joins are properly defined.

Then I check my `WHERE` clause. I run lots of simple queries on the tables, and on the sub-queries that I've already checked or that I already trust, and make sure that when I run the larger query, I'm getting what I expect with the `WHERE` conditions in place. I double-check the `JOIN` conditions at the same time.

I double-check my column definitions to make sure I'm retrieving what I really want to see, especially if the formulas involved are complicated. If you have something complicated like a coordinated subquery in a column definition

Then I check to see if I'm grouping data properly, making sure that "`DISTINCT`"'s and "`UNION`"'s without `UNION ALL` don't remove necessary duplicates.

I don't think I've ever encountered a SQL query that couldn't be broken down this way. I'm not always as methodical as this, but it's a good way to start breaking down a real stumper.

---

One thing I could recommend when you write your queries is this: **Never use `SELECT *` in production code.** Selecting all columns this way is a maintenance nightmare, and it leads to big problems when your underlying schemas change. You should always write out each and every column if you're writing SQL code that you'll be maintaining in the future. I saved myself a lot of time and worry just by getting rid of "`SELECT *`"'s in my projects.

The downside to this is that those extra columns won't appear automatically in queries that refer to "`SELECT *`" queries. But you should be aware of how your queries are related to each other, anyway, and if you need the extra columns, you can go back and add them.

---

There is some hassle involved in maintaining a code repository, but if you have versioning software, the hassle is more than worth it. I've heard of ways of versioning SQL code written in Access databases, but unfortunately, I've never used them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing really complex queries in MS Access, I would consider keeping a repository of those queries somewhere outside of the Access database itself... for instance, in a .sql file that you can then edit in an editor like Intype that will provide syntax highlighting.  It'll require you to update queries in both places, but you may end up finding it handy to have an "official" spot for it that is formatted and highlighted correctly.

Or, if at all possible, switch to SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, which is also free and will provide you the features you desire through the SQL Management Studio (also free).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on this suggestion from Smandoli:

```
NO:   DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT ...")
YES:  strSQL = "SELECT ..."
      DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
```

If you want to keep the SQL code in an external file, for editing with your favorite text editor (with syntax coloring and all that), you could do something like this pseudo-code:

```
// On initialization:
global strSQL
f = open("strSQL.sql")
strSQL = read_all(f)
close(f)

// To to the select:
DoCmd.RunSQL(strSQL)
```

This may be a bit clunky -- maybe a lot clunky -- but it avoids the consistency issues of edit-copy-paste.

Obviously this doesn't directly address debugging SQL, but managing code in a readable way is a part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to **recursive,** I use an external editor to write my queries. I use Notepad++ with the Light Explorer extension for maintaining several scripts at a time, and Notepad2 for one-off scripts. (I'm kind of partial to Scintilla-based editors.)

Another option is to use the free SQL Server Management Studio Express, which comes with SQL Server Express. *(EDIT: Sorry, **EdgarVerona**, I didn't notice you mentioned this already!)* I normally use it to write SQL queries instead of using Access, because I typically use ODBC to link to a SQL Server back end anyway. Beware that the differences in the syntax of T-SQL, used by SQL Server, and Jet SQL, used by Access MDB's, are sometimes substantial.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking here about what MS-Access calls 'queries' and SQL call 'views' or about the 'MS-Access pass-through' queries which are SQL queries? Someone could get easily lost! My solution is the following

1. free SQL Server Management
   Studio Express, where I will
   elaborate and test my queries
2. a query table on the client
   side, with one field for the query
   name (`id_Query`) and another one
   (`queryText`, memo type) for the
   query itself.

I then have a small function `getSQLQuery` in my VBA code to be used when I need to execute a query (either returning a recordset or not):

```
Dim myQuery as string, _
    rsADO as ADODB.recorset

rsADO = new ADODB.recordset
myQuery = getSQLQuery(myId_Query)

'if my query retunrs a recordset'
set rsADO = myADOConnection.Execute myQuery
'or, if no recordset is to be returned'
myADOConnection.Execute myQuery
```

For views, it is even possible to keep them on the server side and to refer to them from the client side

```
set rsADO = myADOConnection.execute "dbo.myViewName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to my knowledge there are 2 options:

- Notepad++ with Poor man's t-sql formatter plugin ..i know there is already a mention for SQL Pretty Printer but i haven't used it..so my workflow is ..i create the query in Access..i copy paste it to Notepad++ ...i format it..i work on it ...back to Access..only issue..it pads in some cases spaces in this case : [Forms]![AForm].[Ctrl] and they become [Forms] ! [AForm].[Ctrl] but i am used to and it doesn't bother me..
- SoftTree SQL Assistant (http://www.softtreetech.com/sqlassist/index.htm)  bring just about everything you wanted on a SQL editor...i have worked a bit in the past(trial) but its price tag is a bit stiff

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the ODBC interface in Access to connect a generic SQL client to (in my case, RazorSQL).

It's not quite right in some of the code-completion spots for Access but much much better than cut and pasting.